# Is it true that there exists a scalar $t$ such that $\langle u_2-tu_1, u_1\rangle = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm trying to prove the following statement :

Suppose $V$ is an inner product space, its dimension is 4, and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ spanned by the basis $\{u_1, u_2\}$. Then there is a scalar $t$ such that $u_2-tu_1$ is perpendicular to $u_1$ (That is, $\langle u_2-tu_1, u_1\rangle = 0$)

As far as I understand the only way I can prove this is to show that $u_2 -tu_1 = 0$ but its impossible since $u_2$ and $u_1$ form a basis to $U$ (That is, there isn't a scalar $t$ such that $u_2=tu_1$ which implies $u_2-tu_1\ne 0$).

Am I missing something? Is it possible that I'm trying to prove a false statement?

Comment: The main point here is detecting and ignoring the irrelevant information. The only relevant information is $\left<u_1,u_1\right>\neq0$ (because $u_1$ appears in a basis). Now you get a $1\times1$ linear system to solve $t$ from, and whose coefficient matrix has nonzero "determinant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
$$
t = \frac{\langle u_1,u_2 \rangle}{\langle u_1,u_1 \rangle}
$$
since the elements of a basis are nonzero. Therefore you have found the scalar $t$ with the required property.

Comment: So obvious and yet I was trying to prove it for a long time. Thank you very much...